# Force/overwrite merge of two tags in svn

Tags: svn, merge

I was wondering if it was in any way possible to merge `tag_1` into `tag_2` such that any conflicts result in `tag_1`'s files overwriting `tag_2`'s files by default. Also, if there are files/dirs in `tag_1` that don't exist in `tag_2` will exist after the merge.

For example, if I was to execute:

```
svn merge http://host/svn/tags/tag_1 http://host/svn/tags/tag_2
```

this would force overwrite and commit all changes and then if I checked out `tag_2`, all of `tag_1`'s additional/altered files would be in the working copy.

Currently, I use a method that runs a diff and then runs `svn rm` on any files of the same name and path in `tag_2` and then `svn cp` the new files in, but it is becoming quite inefficient as releases grow in the number of changed files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use '2-URL Merge' as "Tool of last resort", not needed here
2. Read `svn help merge` carefully for command options
3. If you want merge **to** tag2, you have:

   - Checkout tag_2 into fresh Working Copy, or if it exist, make it Clean WC: no local modifications, no mixed revisions
   - In this WC `svn merge http://host/svn/tags/tag_1 --accept 'mine-conflict'` do the trick (parts without conflicts will be merged, for conflicted chunks "mine" - i.e tag_2 version - will be selected automatically)
   - Commit merge result

**Edit:** Test-run in reply to comment

**Initial state (use trunk and branch)**

```
svn log -q -v file:///Z:/Repo/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | Badger | 2013-01-17 10:07:55 +0600 (Чт, 17 янв 2013)
Changed paths:
   A /branches/MyFixes (from /trunk:2)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | Badger | 2013-01-17 10:03:32 +0600 (Чт, 17 янв 2013)
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/Data
   A /trunk/Data/b.txt
   A /trunk/Data/c.txt
   A /trunk/a.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | Badger | 2013-01-17 09:57:52 +0600 (Чт, 17 янв 2013)
Changed paths:
   A /branches
   A /tags
   A /trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------

svn ls -R file:///Z:/Repo/trunk
Data/
Data/b.txt
Data/c.txt
a.txt

svn ls -R file:///Z:/Repo/branches/MyFixes
Data/
Data/b.txt
Data/c.txt
a.txt
```

**Change branch (edit files, add new objects)**

```
svn log -q -v file:///Z:/Repo/ -l 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | Badger | 2013-01-17 10:26:40 +0600 (Чт, 17 янв 2013)
Changed paths:
   M /branches/MyFixes/Data/b.txt
   M /branches/MyFixes/Data/c.txt
   A /branches/MyFixes/Data/d.txt
   A /branches/MyFixes/NewData
   A /branches/MyFixes/NewData/e.txt
   A /branches/MyFixes/NewData/f.txt
   M /branches/MyFixes/a.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Control diffs for "M"-files**

```
svn diff file:///Z:/Repo/trunk/a.txt file:///Z:/Repo/branches/MyFixes/a.txt
Index: a.txt
===================================================================
--- a.txt       (.../trunk/a.txt)       (revision 4)
+++ a.txt       (.../branches/MyFixes/a.txt)    (revision 4)
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-String 1
-String 2
+A String 1
+A String 2
```

---

```
svn diff file:///Z:/Repo/trunk/Data/b.txt file:///Z:/Repo/branches/MyFixes/Data/b.txt
Index: b.txt
===================================================================
--- b.txt       (.../trunk/Data/b.txt)  (revision 4)
+++ b.txt       (.../branches/MyFixes/Data/b.txt)       (revision 4)
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
-Data String 1
-Data String 2
+The Data String One
+The Data String Two
+The Data String Three
```

---

```
svn diff file:///Z:/Repo/trunk/Data/c.txt file:///Z:/Repo/branches/MyFixes/Data/c.txt
Index: c.txt
===================================================================
--- c.txt       (.../trunk/Data/c.txt)  (revision 4)
+++ c.txt       (.../branches/MyFixes/Data/c.txt)       (revision 4)
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
-String 1 data
-String 2 data
+1 Los datos de cadena
+Cadena 2 Datos
+Cadena 3 Datos
```

**Try to merge**

```
z:\Trunk>svn merge file:///Z:/Repo/branches/MyFixes --accept "mine-conflict" --dry-run
--- Merging r3 through r4 into '.':
A    NewData
A    NewData\e.txt
A    NewData\f.txt
U    Data\b.txt
U    Data\c.txt
A    Data\d.txt
U    a.txt
```

Impression - none conflicts (as expected), none tree-conflicts (as expected by me), diverged files merged, new from branch - added

**Real merging**

```
z:\Trunk>svn merge file:///Z:/Repo/branches/MyFixes --accept "mine-conflict"
--- Merging r3 through r4 into '.':
U    Data\b.txt
U    Data\c.txt
A    Data\d.txt
U    a.txt
A    NewData
A    NewData\e.txt
A    NewData\f.txt
--- Recording mergeinfo for merge of r3 through r4 into '.':
 U   .
```

**Commit merge**

```
svn log -q -v file:///Z:/Repo/ -l 1
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r5 | Badger | 2013-01-17 10:50:35 +0600 (Чт, 17 янв 2013)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk
   M /trunk/Data/b.txt
   M /trunk/Data/c.txt
   A /trunk/Data/d.txt (from /branches/MyFixes/Data/d.txt:4)
   A /trunk/NewData (from /branches/MyFixes/NewData:4)
   M /trunk/a.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Attention - Problem!

Maybe I edited files erroneously in branch (a/b/c), but for some strange reasons `--accept "mine-conflict"` was ignored and files after merge are equal to their branch's parents.

**Addition:** OK, I forgot edit also a/b/c in trunk before merging. Mea culpa, must work as expected totally after adding this point

Comment: This largely works, accept for whenever I have common directories in `tag_2`, I get tree conflict errors and no files in that dir are changed. e.g. if there was `tag_2/foo/file.py` and I merged `tag_1`, which had `tag_1/foo/anotherFile.py`, **to** `tag_2`, I get a tree conflict and `tag_2/foo/` remains unchanged.

Comment: Tree conflicts can only be resolved using "svn resolve (whatever) --accept working"